# Issue with logstash date filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to use **date** filter in logstash.config. 
My understanding about **data** filter is that it picks the timestamp field the log file. This timestamp is used by the logstash to sort the logs so that in kibana we see a sorted logs. Please correct me if my understanding is right or is there anything more about **date** filter.

below is my logstash config.

```
filter {    
  grok {
   match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp} %{IP:FromClient} %{NUMBER:sizeOfFile} This is log level \[%{LOGLEVEL:rollno}\]"}
 }

date {
    match => [ "TimeStamp", "ISO8601" ]
    remove_field => [ "TimeStamp" ]
}

 if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
  drop { }
    }
}
```

If i keep **date** filter in the config file, i dont see ang logs coming to kibana. but if i take out **date** filter from config, i can see logs reflecting in kibana. May i please know how **date** filter is influencing here.

In both the cases, filebeat is sending the logs to logstash and i can see it in logstash.

Please help me here.

Comment: Did you check logstash logs when the date filter is in your config file? Does it show any errors? Your configuration looks like it should work for you.

Comment: @DianaZvulun ..This is my grok filter ...  match => {"message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}\]\[%{WORD:machineName}\]\[%{JAVACLASS:className}\]\[%{JAVAMETHOD:methodName}\]\[%{GREEDYDATA:myMessage}\]"}

Comment: date {
    match => [ "TimeStamp", "ISO8601" ]
    #remove_field => [ "TimeStamp" ]
}

Comment: I get **_dateparsefailure** in logstash. Is this the reason for logs not visible in kibana. Please help me

Comment: what about the logstash logs? are there any errors there?